# How to do filtering based on logics using pandas group by

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id' : [1, 1, 2,2, 3,3], 
               'Qty' : [4,4,8,8,5,5], 
               'Vendor Price' : [23,43, 100, 40, 1000, 1400],
               'Qty Avail' :[0, 8, 2, 8, 0, 8]})

Out[159]: 
     Id  Qty  Vendor Price  Qty Avail
 0   1    4            23          0
 1   1    4            43          8
 2   2    8           100          2
 3   2    8            40          8
 4   3    5          1000          0
 5   3    5          1400          8
```

I want to apply the logic that if group by Id, Qty Avail<
Qty<
Qty Avail  then return min(Qty Avail) Vendor Price else return max(Qty Avail)vendor price, so the data frame will look like

```
 Id  Qty  Vendor Price  Qty Avail
 1    4            23          0
 2    8            40          8
 3    5          1000          0
```

I am not able to get the logic for doing this. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your logic doesn't make a lot of sense as stated as you have multiple Qty Avail per id. so grouping by first means you can't directly resolve whether Qty< Qty Avail is true of false for a given id.

that being said your derived output appears to want you to select the smallest vendor price and largest qty availability among those where qty >= qty avail.

if that is the case you can use

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Qty'] >= df['Qty Avail'] ,['Id','Qty','Vendor Price']].groupby(['Id', 'Qty']).min()

df2 = df.loc[df['Qty'] >= df['Qty Avail'] ,['Id','Qty','Qty Avail']].groupby(['Id', 'Qty']).max()
```

then join these on id

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working fine tested with all other conditions.

Comment: i edited what i thought was a mistake in my answer only to find out that the unedited version was working as expected. Does anyone know how to revert my answer back to the pre-edited version?

Answer (score 2):

From what i understand , use this:

```
m=df.groupby(['Id','Qty'])['Qty Avail'].agg(['first','last']).reset_index()
m['Qty Avail']=np.where((m.Qty.gt(m['first']))&(m.Qty.lt(m['last'])),m['first'],m['last'])
df.merge(m[['Id','Qty Avail']],on=['Id','Qty Avail'])

   Id  Qty  Vendor Price  Qty Avail
0   1    4            23          0
1   2    8            40          8
2   3    5          1000          0
```